# How do I say to Eclipse where to save my compiled packages to another path?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, package

So I have this Java Eclipse project where I use a custom package:

```
Project/
        src/
            defaultpackage/
                           *.jar
            mypackage/
                      class1.java, 
                      class2.java ...
```

How do I say to Eclipse where to compile all **mypackage** classes as **mypackage.jar** in a different output folder? I know that by default Eclipse will create the jar's inside the project directory.

My idea is to have a folder for my compiled packages **out of the project structure**, actually create **myjarlib** folder, so everytime I compile a different package will create a `/ ... / myjarlib / newpackage.jar` only if I specified this for the **newpackage**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your structure example, the 'src' folder is a source folder. You can configure where eclipse emits the compile-on-save generated class files on a per-source-folder basis.

You cannot configure this on a per-package basis.

So, change it at the source folder level. If you want one package to go in directory A, and the other package to go to directory B, make 2 source folders, and configure for each. Example:

```
Project
    src
        main
            pkg1
                SomeJavaCode.java
        test
            pkg2
                SomeTestCode.java
```

Here Project/src/main is a source package (containing the source for class pkg1.SomeJavaCode), as is Project/src/test. right click on the project and select 'properties' to modify which directory(ies) are source folders. Also in the 'properties' of any project (not the source folder), go to section 'Java Build Path', pick the "Source" tab, click on the sourcefolder you want to edit, mark the 'allow output folders for source folders' option (by default, eclipse sends the compile-on-save results of all source folders to the same folder, this checkbox lets you configure it on a per-folder basis), and configure it.

Comment: Then, to create your jar files, use the eclipse Export facility - right click on the project, select Export>Java>JAR File and select your source folder plus options.

Comment: Under `project` I have: `src main` with `default package` and `src support` containing my `custom packages` filled with `CustomClass.java` files          which actually solves [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137336/how-do-i-do-in-eclipse-to-build-my-custom-java-package-and-project-at-the-same-t). This way I don't have to create jar files in a compulsory way. /// @rzwitserloot, it seems that I can't choose a different output folder for those src folders. If I choose an output folder everything goes there after compilation in form of .class files. (but no problem).

Comment: @TonyWeddle, thanks, because optionally I could compact all my custom classes on a package category having a JAR file of them. But I've just tried and the only output folder Eclipse lets me choose is a `bin` under `project` even if I select another `...\myjarlib` out of project structure. (But no problem by now). This is also related to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137336/how-do-i-do-in-eclipse-to-build-my-custom-java-package-and-project-at-the-same-t). Thanks both for the help!